# Castle.ActiveRecord.PropertyAttribute.NotNull... documentation bug?

Tags: c#, activerecord, castle-activerecord

The [documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord-READONLY/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Attributes/PropertyAttribute.cs) for this property states that the boolean `NotNull` property:

```
true if allow null; otherwise, false.
```

This seems to be the exact opposite of what it should be.  Am I reading this the wrong way, or is this a bug?  If it is a bug, is it a documentation bug or an implementation bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently it's a documentation bug.  I will submit a patch.

Comment: submitted and merged.